# Why doesn't the following component render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code living under Carousel.js.

```js
import React from 'react';

export default class Carousel extends React.Component {
  render() {

    const estatesArray = [
      {name: "The Villa", url: "www.google.ca", type: "Villa"},
      {name: "The Apartment", url: "www.google.ca", type: "Apartment"}
    ];

    const listItems = estatesArray.map((obj) => {
      <li> {obj.name} + {obj.url} </li>
    });

    return (
        <ul>
          {listItems}
        </ul>
    );
  };
};
```

It should work perfectly fine. It is the exact same map function as in the react.js documentation with only minor changes. I don't understand why when I call it on my Home component (like so: <"Carousel />, without the quote), it displays an empty  tag. Any insights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const listItems = estatesArray.map((obj) => {
    <li> {obj.name} + {obj.url} </li>
});
```

the mapping callback has no return

you want either

```
const listItems = estatesArray.map((obj) => {
  return <li> {obj.name} + {obj.url} </li>
});
```

or

```
const listItems = estatesArray.map((obj) => (
  <li> {obj.name} + {obj.url} </li>
));
```

any don't forget to include a `key` prop on your `li`s.

Comment: God I feel stupid I hadn't noticed I was using curly brackets. Thank you Tyler.

Comment: see the last thing I wrote, as well, it's more important than you think

Comment: Yes thank you, I was going to do this afterwards! just kinda figuring things out right now.